# Scala XML change literal node

Tags: xml, scala, replace, nodes

For now I have XML Like this:

```
<root>
<snippet>
  <title></title>
  <content></content>
</snippet>
<snippet>
  <title></title>
  <content></content>
</snippet>
<snippet>
  <title></title>
  <content></content>
</snippet>
.
.
.
</root>
```

And i wana replace n snippet example:

```
   xml = XML.loadFile(xmlFilePath)
    val snippets = xml \\ "root" \\ "snippet"
```

Now I can refer to each by 
snippets(1),snippets(2),snippets(3) etc.

And now how to change/replace for example snippets(5)

Answer (score 0):

The following code may solve your problem(Scala version 2.11.4).

```
val snippets = originalXML \\ "root" \\ "snippet"
snippets.zipWithIndex map {
    case (node, index) => { // index starts from 0
        if (index == 4) 
            // the new content
            <snippet>
                <title>foo</title>
                <content>bar</content>
            </snippet>
        else node
    }
}
```